# How to disprove a limit of series?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$a_{n} = \dfrac{7n^{3} - 3n^{4} -1}{4n^{2} + 3}$$
I want to show that this series has no limit.
So, I know I need to show that $\exists \epsilon >0, \forall N\exists n > N $,$ |a_{n} - L | \geq \epsilon $

What is the method to find this $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: You've forgotten $\forall L$ in the very beginning. But an easier approach would be to show that $a_n$ is unbounded; it had to be bounded would it converge to some limit

Comment: how can you show that this series is unbounded? it sounds harder than the limit contradiction@

Comment: Focus on the leading terms of numerator and denominator. Dividing top and bottom by $n^3$, you get $$a_n = \dfrac{7-3n-\frac{1}{n^3}}{4+\frac{3}{n^3}}$$. Now you can see the numerator grows without bound, but the denominator is bounded.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: you got a wrong limit, and even for that you got a wrong outcome.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: I think OP really means "sequence", not "series". He doesn't appear to be summing these terms. You missed the 4th degree term in the numerator too.

Comment: @nofc: No, what I wrote was exactly right. I just divided every term, top and bottom, by $n^3$.

Comment: @MPW see the edit sorry

Comment: @nofc: Oh, I see you changed the question after I posted my comment. Ok. I can't edit that comment now, so...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a series, but a sequence. We have:

$$ a_n = \frac{-3n^4+7n^3-1}{4n^3+3} = -\frac{3n}{4}+\frac{28n^3+9n-4}{16n^3+12}=-\frac{3n-7}{4}+\frac{9n-25}{16n^3+12}$$
but since:
$$\frac{9n-25}{16n^3+12}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$
for any $n\geq 1$ we have that:
$$\left|a_n+\frac{3n}{4}\right|<2.\tag{1}$$
A straightforward consequence of $(1)$ is that for any $n$ big enough, $a_n$ is negative and unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to show that the sequence is unbounded. Notice that $a_n\approx-\frac34n$ for big $n$, so the idea is that $a_n$ is really negative for sufficiently large $n$. Following the @MPW's representation, you can notice that $a_n \leq-\frac37n+\frac74$ which is clearly unbounded.